# Get different random value each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting

I was stuck on something. I want a user able to pick a value from an array. But the challenge is he/she couldn't get the same value as previous one.

https://jsbin.com/hibihubega/edit?html,js,console,output

I don't know how to proceed, help.

```
function getNum(){
  var num = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

var selected = num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)];
var history = selected;

  if(history){

  }

}

$('button').click(function(){
  console.log(getNum());
})
```

Comment: remove the element from array after selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     num = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
     temp =[];

    $("button").on("click",function(){

        getNum();

    })

    function getNum(){

        if ( num.length <= 0  ) {
            num = temp;
            temp =[];  
        }

        var indexRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*(num.length));
        console.log(num[indexRandom]);
        temp.push(num[indexRandom]);
        num.splice(indexRandom,1);
    }

})
```

**Final code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <button>dfdgdfg</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
$(document).ready(function() {
    
     num = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
     temp =[];
    
    $("button").on("click",function(){
        
        getNum();
        
    })
    
    function getNum(){
        
        if ( num.length <= 0  ) {
            
            num = temp;
            temp =[];
            
        }
            
             var indexRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*(num.length));
            console.log(num[indexRandom]);
             temp.push(num[indexRandom]);
             num.splice(indexRandom,1);
    }
            
})
        
            
        </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: this is working but how to reset the array back, I can't have an alert saying the array is empty lol.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the value after selection, and replace before the next selection.

Here's how you could format your code:

```
var num,
    lastNum,
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function newNum(){
    lastNum && numbers.push(lastNum);
    lastNum = num;
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    num = numbers[r];
    numbers.splice(r,1);
}

$("button").click(function(){
    newNum();
    console.log(num);
})
```

The picked number is random, but never the last chosen one.

Comment: In order for that to work. The `num` array has to be defined outside of the `getNum()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the value with **[splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)** after using it.

```
function getNum() {
    if (num.length==0){
        return false;
    } else {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)
        var selected = num[index];
        num.splice(index, 1); //remove from array
        return selected;
    }
}
```

And if you want to save initial, create another (clone) of initial array and reduce that.

Comment: will it caused error if the array item is empty after so many click?

Comment: why would it cause an error? it takes index always from array size. if it's empty, you can .. well. I added `if` expression

Comment: I added `if` expression to full function. returns `false` if array is empty. Returns number if array is not empty

Comment: return false will get nothing, in my case user will always get something thanks

Comment: it's just one way of how to interpret the function. you didn't specify what you wanted when array is empty, so i just returned false.